# why this javascript expression returns "e"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

the following expression returns "e"

```
alert(["a","b","c","d","e"][[1,2],3,4]);
```

can anybody tell me why? thanks!

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do?

Comment: OK, now I'm curious. Why isn't this a syntax error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is break down the expression:

```
[
    [1,2],
    3,
    4 
]
```

You are using bracket notation to access a property on the array literal. The syntax requires an expression. The syntax of an expression allows a single expression to contain many expressions when separated by a comma. Each term of the expression is evaluated left to right and the final value is actually the value of the last term. So your example can be replaced with this:

```
alert(["a","b","c","d","e"][4]);
```

Comment: @fireeyedboy - Don't take my word on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator

Comment: +1 Alright, we have a winner. :) You could have fooled me into a lot of things with this weird use of syntax. :D

Answer (score 0):

["a","b","c","d","e"] is an array and "e" has index 4 in this array. The second part of this expression accesses the array element, for example, if you try ["a","b","c","d","e"][4] you will get "e". I think this part of expression "[1,2],3," is ignored.